# Binding to a ng-model from a directive to access $dirty and $valid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just wanted to know if there was a way to bind to formName.firstName.$dirty and formName.firstName.$valid inside of a directive.  I wrote a from using the standard angular binding. here is my code:

```
<form action="#" name="formName">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <span ng-show="contact.firstName.$dirty" class="ng-hide">
            <span ng-show="contact.firstName.$valid" class="ng-hide"> <img src="images/check.png" alt=""></span>
            <span ng-show="contact.firstName.$invalid"> <img src="images/error.png" alt=""></span>
        </span>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control" ng-pattern="/\b[A-Za-z|\'|\s]{2,}\b/" ng-model="firstName"
               ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur change', debounce: 500 }" required=""
               placeholder="enter your first name">
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to take the spans and make them into a directive so I can re-use it. So my code would look like this.
(code I want to use, **not real code**)

```
<form action="#" name="formName>
    <feedback model="firstName">
        <input type="text" name="model" class="form-control" ng-pattern="/\b[A-Za-z|\'|\s]{2,}\b/" ng-model="model"
               ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur change', debounce: 500 }" required=""
               placeholder="enter your first name">
    </feedback>
</form>
```

Is there way to bind to $valid, $invalid and $dirty inside the directive and trigger it based on the form model.  I am not sure if I am asking the question correctly. I hope the code explains my intent.

I can post something I wrote if necessary or put up something on jsbin or plunkr. I have seen similar code where people have emulated the code for ng-model using element.bind(), I was hoping there was a more angularish way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the attribute to the directive scope.
Like this

```js
app.directive('feedback', [function(version) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            dirty: '=dirty'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch('dirty', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                console.log('form:', newValue);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

```html
<feedback dirty="formName.firstName.$dirty"></feedback>
```

Comment: You can also bind your ng-model, and watch it.

Comment: Thank You for the response I will give it a try and accept once I get a chance to test it out.

Comment: If you think this answer solves your problem, plz accept it.